# How to select a function as well as select from table

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table `tb` with some data, say:

```
A   B 
__|__
1 | 1
2 | 2
```

Is there a way to do a `SELECT * FROM tb` along with a select of a function, say `SELECT NOW()` and end up with something like:

```
1 | 1 | datetime
2 | 2 | datetime
```

Or if it's any different, `SELECT * FROM tb WHERE A=1` and `SELECT NOW()` to give

`1 | 1 | datetime` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, like :-

```
select A, B, now() as some_column_name from tb;
```

Or :-

```
select A,B from tb
inner join (select now()) as date_time
where A=1;
```

Comment: oops, I checked the second way again and it's actually not showing the date_time column. Do you have to select date_time in the first line somehow?

Comment: oh, use the first method better